# Add hidden text in outlook web addin email

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have a requirement to keep some hidden text in user outgoing email. So that when we doing user mail copy in backend, we extract those hidden text and do some processing.

I am trying to add `div` like below :

```html
<div class="customerClass">
  <span style="color:white;display:none" class="CustomerClass">hidden Text</span>
</div>
```

But Outlook for Mac is stripping all `div` tags, and `class` property of `span` tags.

What is effective way to pass custom information with outgoing mail using Outlook Web Add-in API's?

Comment: Could you add the code you're using to insert this into the email body?

Comment: please check the code : https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/72f5582852208de2d7616a9094328e70

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT any help regarding my question? why it is failing in native outlook of mac?

Comment: I'll need to set up something to try and replicate. I suspect the issue is using `class` since this isn't something email HTML variants use. Possible it is trying to "help" but need make replicate to be sure.